# How to remove <script src=""> appended in the body (Laravel + Inertia + Svelte)?

Tags: laravel, svelte, inertiajs

I'm converting a HTML template into Laravel + Inertia + Svelte app, because it is far easier than using a Svelte template, especially if it has store and etc. One of the problem with this template is that, instead of using 1 giant JavaScript and CSS files, it separates them into tiny piece-by-piece JS and CSS. So each of the pages of this template has at least 1 different JS and CSS file. It's fine for a HTML template tho, but I need to workaround things so that it doesn't conflict in my Laravel + Inertia + Svelte app.

My workaround to add those different file is to append it to the end of the body, using this code:

```
    let passwordAddonInitJS = document.createElement('script');
    passwordAddonInitJS.setAttribute('src', '/assets/js/pages/password-addon.init.js');
    document.body.appendChild(passwordAddonInitJS);
```

And it works well. That script is loaded into my Login page. Now here is the problem. I have another 2 pages, Forgot Password page (where the user input email to be emailed a password reset link) and Reset Password page (where the user input new password). For the Reset Password page, I loaded a new JS file using this code:

```
    let passwordCreateInitJS = document.createElement('script');
    passwordCreateInitJS.setAttribute('src', '/assets/js/pages/passowrd-create.init.js');
    document.body.appendChild(passwordCreateInitJS);
```

When I click the reset password link that is sent to my email, the browser shows Reset Password page with the script above. However, after the user successfully reset their password, they will be redirected into Login Page. This is where the problem is.

The problem is that in the Login Page, the "passowrd-create.init.js" is still exist and then the browser add the "password-addon.init.js". Which makes them conflict with each other.

The correct way that I wanted is:

- Remove "passowrd-create.init.js" after redirect from Reset Password page to Login page
- Then add "password-addon.init.js" in the Login page

How do I suppose to do this in Svelte?

Answer (score 0):

Removing a script from the document does not magically unload or undo everything in it, so this will not resolve anything.

You should make sure that the scripts themselves do not affect pages they are not meant to affect.

If the scripts contain Svelte components with their own cleanup logic ([`onDestroy`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#ondestroy)), you should compile them to [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), import the component and [instantiate the component locally](https://svelte.dev/docs/client-side-component-api#creating-a-component) and [`$destroy`](https://svelte.dev/docs/client-side-component-api#$destroy) it when appropriate (probably some hook of your client-side router).